# How to set the Android APK only seen by tablet user or phone user in google market?

Tags: android, permissions

I have written an Android Application with tablet and mobile phone version. Since the two version have little difference, I 'd like to make two APK files for mobile phone and tablet respectively. Can I set some permission in manifest file so that the google market can screen the suitable version?

In other word, when the user is using tablet, he/she can just search the tablet version.
When the user is using phone, he/she can just search the phone version.

Answer (score 1):

you Should Go with [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) for your Solution.

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

Comment: Are you sure it covers permissions too?